# Compactness on set with two topologies

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Question : Let $\Omega_1 \subset \Omega_2$ be two topological structures in $X$. Does the compactness of $(X, \Omega_2)$ imply that of $(X, \Omega_1)$?  And vice versa?

My attempt : Assuming the space is compact wrt. $\Omega_1$ we can find a finite subcover for open sets in $\Omega_1$ then these sets are also in $\Omega_2$ thus the space is compact in $\Omega_2$ BUt this argument is wrong. What am i missing ?

Comment: Saying the set is compact with respect to  Ω1 means that, given any cover by sets in  Ω1 there exist a finite subcover.  It does NOT follow that any cover by sets in  Ω2, which may NOT be in  Ω1, has that property.  Do you see that the other way is true- that if the set is compact with respect to  Ω2  then it is compact with respect to  Ω1?

Comment: No. I cant understand that statement either :(

Comment: Compactness is preserved "downward" — if $\Omega_2$ is compact then so is $\Omega_1$. An open cover of $X$ by sets in $\Omega_1$ is also an open cover in $\Omega_2$, so it has a finite subcover; but all members of the subcover are in $\Omega_1$ (and of course their union doesn't depend on the topology).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $X$ compact with respect to $\Omega_1$. Choose an arbitrary open cover with respect to $\Omega_2$. Is this an open cover with respect to $\Omega_1$ too, in order for you to be able to extract an open subcover with respect to $\Omega_1$? No, because open sets from $\Omega_2$ do not necessarilly belong to $\Omega_1$.

The converse, though, is true. Assume $X$ compact with respect to $\Omega_2$. Choose an arbitrary open cover  $\Omega_1$. This is still an open cover with respect to $\Omega_2$. Pick *here* an finite subcover. This will also be an open subcover with respect to $\Omega_1$, because the open subsets were originally from $\Omega_1$. Therefore $X$ is compact with respect to $\Omega_1$.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $X$ is compact wrt $\Omega_2$. We need to show that it is compact wrt $\Omega_1$. Let $\{U_\alpha\}$ be an open cover of $X$ in $\Omega_1$. That is each $U_\alpha$ is in $\Omega_1$. This means each $U_\alpha$ is in $\Omega_2$ and $X$ is compact in $\Omega_2$ so we have a finite subcover $U_{\alpha_1},\cdots ,U_{\alpha_n}$ of $X$ which is what we needed.

Conversely, if $X$ is compact in $\Omega_1$ it need not be compact in $\Omega_2$. Consider for example $\Omega_1$ is the indiscrete topology and $\Omega_2$ is the discrete topology on $X$ and $X$ is an infinite set.